# Can I make bleach for laundry from sodium dichloro-s-triazinetrione

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, everyday-chemistry

According to [The Organic Prepper](https://www.theorganicprepper.com/how-to-make-bleach-from-pool-shock/), one can generate bleach from pool shock.

> The good news is, you can make your own bleach with granular calcium hypochlorite, the primary component of typical pool shock. It’s essential to confirm that your pool shock is not contaminated by other chemicals, such as algicides. Only HTH is acceptable for purifying your water.

However, this uses calcium hypochlorite ($\ce{CaOCl}$). Upon research, I found out that there are three types of pool shock available - calcium hypochlorite, sodium hypochlorite and sodium dichloro-s-triazinetrione. The shock that I have is sodium dichloro-s-triazinetrione and not calcium hypochlorite.

Is it possible to make bleach (or something that does a similar action) using this sodium dichloro-s-triazinetrione?

Comment: Steps they used were adding 1/2 tsp pool shock to 1 gallon water. Did not know there are 3 types of shock.

Answer (score 4):

If you simply want to clean clothes, you can use all these solutions. Sodium hypochlorite, calcium hypochlorite, dichloro-s-triazinetrione have all the same oxidizing effect in solution. They will all oxidize and destroy stains on dirty clothes.

Comment: Thank you Maurice!!! I have small dogs with small bladders and use belly bands (diaper for male dog peeing) for overnite, so not even important wash, and have enough pool shock to make $1000 worth of bleach then.